# U-SQL Ignore rows causing JSON exception in JsonFunctions.JsonTuple() after using Text Extractor

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to convert JSON files into csv, extracting some specific key/values of interest. I have large text files (> 1 million lines) where each line is a JSON object. The actual structure is nested and contains arrays, but it shouldn't be important for this question.

Example file:

```
{"param1": val00, "param2": val01}
{"param1": val10, "param2": val11}
...
{"param1": valn0, "param2": valn1}
```

I'm using the following code with Text Extractor to convert each line to a JSON object, and subsequently parsing the JSON object using JsonFunctions.JsonTuple()

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY DdaAdlDb.[Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY DdaAdlDb.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

@RawExtract = 
    EXTRACT RawString string
    FROM @InputFile 
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'\b', quoting:false);

@json =
    SELECT JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(RawString, "..*") AS RootObject
    FROM @RawExtract;
```

I run into problems because at least one of the lines is corrupt, as follows:

```
{"param1": val00, "param2"{"param1": val10, "param2": val11}
...
{"param1": valn0, "param2": valn1}
```

These are the error messages I receive

> VertexFailedFast: Vertex failed with a fail-fast error
>   E_RUNTIME_USER_EXPRESSIONEVALUATION
>   Error while evaluating expression Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(RawString, "..*")
>   Inner exception from user expression: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {.
>
> ==== Caught exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue(Boolean ignoreComments) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r, JsonLoadSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings options) at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ReadFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings) at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple[T](String json, String[] paths) at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(String json, String[] paths) at **_Scope_Generated_Classes_**.SqlFilterTransformer_13.Process(IRow inRow, IUpdatableRow outRow) in d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\45905a29-60cf-4dd2-bf9c-c2b31bedea60\appcache\application_1546207842059_5159256\container_e346_1546207842059_5159256_01_000001\wd__ScopeCodeGen__.dll.cs:line 233

I don't mind losing a few lines. I see that for extractors I can use `silent: true` to ignore bad rows. Is there a similar option for the `JsonFunctions.JsonTuple()` parsing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was possible to create a try-catch block within the U-SQL script to avoid crash on `JsonReaderException`.

**Try-catch block**

```
// Ignore rows with invalid JSON formattting
DECLARE @TryParseJson Func<string, SqlMap<string, string>> = (RawString)=>{
    try 
    {
        return JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(RawString, "..*");
    }
    catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException e)
    {
        return null;  // Consider returning empty SqlMap<string, string> instead
    }
};
```

**Extract and parse JSON**

Each line contains a JSON string

```
@RawExtract = 
    EXTRACT RawString string
    FROM @InputFile 
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'\b', quoting:false);

@json =
    SELECT @TryParseJson(RawString) AS RootObject
    FROM @RawExtract;
```

**Ignore rows with invalid JSON (null value)**

```
@result =
    SELECT RootObject["id"] AS Id
         , RootObject["status"] AS Status
         , RootObject["time"] AS Time
    FROM @json
    WHERE RootObject != null;  // Ignore invalid JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar option for JsonTuple.

I see 2 options to deal with that problem.

1. Create code behind to catch the error
2. Write your own version of JsonFunctions that handles the error.

The source code is here:
https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json/JsonFunctions.cs